# jqgrid - postData submits previous request params and data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have been using `postData` to set the request params dynamically. On click of some external button, I change the grid URL and also set some additional params in `postData` like below. JqGrid seems to append all these params and it's data for all the subsequent requests. Is there a way we can control or avoid these params being sent every time?

My grid definition:

```
jQuery(function() {
    $('#grid').jqGrid({
    url: 'rates.html',
    postData: {
        name: function() { return $("#name").val(); },
        rate: function() { return $("#rate").val(); },
                .....
        }
        ....
    });
});
```

Here in the post request: I see that `name`, `rate` params are going along with other standard jqGrid parameters like `sortname`, `sidx`, `rows`, etc...

Now if on click of an external button, if I change the grid URL like below

```
$('#changeReqBtn').click(function() {
       $('#grid').setGridParam({ url: 'changeReq.html', 
                              postData: { msgIds: msgIds } });
       $('#grid').trigger("reloadGrid");     

});
```

Now jqGrid sends `name`, rate, `msgIds` params

Now if I change the URL back to rates.html say for example, on click of refresh icon, jqGrid sends the previous `msgIds` param and also the previous values. I don't want to send the previous request params in the new request when the URL changes. Is there a way we can achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I correct understand your problem you should avoid usage of `setGridParam` and do the following instead. You can use `$('#grid').jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData")` to get **the reference** to the internal parameter `postData`. For example,

```js
var myPostData = $('#grid').jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData");
```

So you can use `delete myPostData.msgIds` to delete any property of the method previously added by `setGridParam`.

Comment: Thank you Oleg. Looks like we need to manually remove the object parameter once the reload is done. I was manually resetting the param to null once the reload is done, deletion is a better approach. Thanks..

Comment: I've tried this but `myPostData` is always *undefined* - is there something missing on my side?

Comment: @Matt: It's important *when* and *in which context* you try to use the code. It's better that you post the code, which you use and which not works like expected, in the new question.

Comment: @Oleg: Yes, you are right. I finally made it work for me, I've posted it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17655769/1016343) - hopefully it will help someone to save time; jqGrid can really be tricky!

Comment: @RangaNirmana: You are welcome! I recommend you to do the following too: `var p = $('#grid').jqGrid("getGridParam");` It get you *reference* to internal object of jqGrid with all internal parameters. You can get any specific parameter like `p.postData` or `p.rowNum` and modify it if required. You don't need to use `setGridParam` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue of preserving postdata parameters from previous requests.

I fixed it by clearing postData first and then setting postData with new parameters.

clearing postData => $('#grid1').setGridParam({ postData: ""});

setting postData with new parameters =>

var formValues = {searchVal: "abc", country: "US"}
$('#grid1').setGridParam({ postData: formValues});

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it this way:

```
function triggerRefresh(wsParams) {
    // determine ws path
    var myGrid=$('#myjsTreeView');
    var urlData = "/myWebService.asmx/myWebServiceMethod";
    // note: you need to pass url, datatype, postdata
    var gridParam = { url: urlData, datatype: "json", postData: wsParams, page: 1 };                        
    myGrid.jqGrid('setGridParam', gridParam).trigger("reloadGrid");
} // function
```

The difference is that I specify `datatype`, the `url` and the `page` altogether in my request - which made it work!

I call this function like so:

```
var myparams = $.toJSON({ para1: someValue, para2: someOtherValue });
triggerRefresh(myparams);
```

when I require the data to be updated. Omitting the datatype for example will cause the refresh to fail silently.